# Change array index with array.map()

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it somehow possible to iterate an array in JS using `Array.map()` and modify the *index* values of the resulting array?

```
// I start with this values:
var arrSource = [
  {id:7, name:"item 1"}, 
  {id:10, name:"item 2"},
  {id:19, name:"item 3"},
];

var arrResult = arrSource.map(function(obj, index) {
    // What to do here?
    return ???; 
});

/*
This is what I want to get as result of the .map() call:

arrResult == [
  7: {id:7, name:"item 1"}, 
  10: {id:10, name:"item 2"},
  19: {id:19, name:"item 3"},
];
*/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `Array#map` performs a 1:1 mapping (so to speak).

You'd have to create a new array and explicitly assign the elements to the specific indexes:

```
var arrResult = [];
arrSource.forEach(function(value) {
   arrResult[value.id] = value;
});
```

Of course you can use `.reduce` for that too.

Comment: Yes, alternatively `map` then `sort`.

Comment: @Vld: Not sure how either of these would help here.

Comment: Actually, you're right. I misread the question thinking OP wants to map then re-order.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do it as follows;

```js
var arrSource = [
  {id:7, name:"item 1"}, 
  {id:10, name:"item 2"},
  {id:19, name:"item 3"},
];

newArr = arrSource.map((e,i,a) => a[a.length-1-i]);
console.log(newArr)
```

Yes... always the source array gets mutated if you need some irregularities with `Array.prototype.map()` such as

```js
var arrSource = [
  {id:7, name:"item 1"}, 
  {id:10, name:"item 2"},
  {id:19, name:"item 3"},
];

newArr = arrSource.map((e,i,a) => a[a.length] = e);
console.log(JSON.stringify(arrSource,null,4));
```

which is not surprising.

Comment: That just seems to reverse the order of elements.

Comment: @Felix Kling Yes.. or whatever order you like depending on your logic.

Comment: But that's not what the OP wants to do. The OP wants to assign `arr[0]` to `arr[7]`, `arr[1]` to `arr[10]`, etc.

Comment: @Felix Kling and in this particular snippet we are assigning `arr[2]`  to `arr[0]`

Comment: Sure. The point is that you cannot assign to **arbitrary** indexes via `.map`. You can only assign to indexes that already have a value (i.e. exist). But even then, you cannot really control to which index something is assigned to. You have to think the other way round: What do I want to assign to index `i`? And since in your example index `7` will never be processed it's not possible to achieve what the OP wants with `.map`.

Comment: Nice ides. But this solution also modifies the source array. When you call the function more than once it could produce duplicate results (unless we can also delete() the original items, which is even more messy)

Comment: @Phillipp Sure Felix Kling is right we must remain within the limits of the source array length when map is used. Hacks are possible as shown in the added snippet but then there is no point of using map. BTW first snippet doesn't mutate the source array as long as you remain within the map space of the source array.

Comment: @Philipp .map() doesn't modify the original array but create a new one